# Get last 90 days records (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause

I have the following query to get the last 90 days records from my DB.

Sample Data below:

[image: sample data]

my query code:

```
SELECT
Email
,Country
,Date_of_Birth
,Date_Added
,Received_ProfileCompletionPromoCode
,First_Name
,Purchase_since_entry
,Exit_Date
FROM
Profile_Completion_Journey_Exit_Log
WHERE
Exit_Date >= DATEADD(d, -90, GETDATE())
```

But I am getting the result where Exit_Date is 10/11/2020. What would be my error here?

Comment: October 10th (assuming that's what 10/11/2020 means) is within the last 90 days. What is the problem?

Comment: Oh okaaaay, I thought my code will be getting the records that is 90 days ago in the DB.

Comment: I should be getting the records past 90 days from todays date. So should be July 27 2020?

Comment: Wow, you're so lucky to have the #1 and #2 answer the exact same within seconds.  That should give you confidence in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code gives you records whose date is not older than 90 days ago.

If you want records whose date is exactly 90 days ago, then:

```
WHERE Exit_Date = DATEADD(day, -90, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

The conversion to date is an important step. `GETDATE()` returns the current date *and time*: we need to truncate the time part.

This assumes that `Exit_Date` is of `date` datatype. If it has a time component, then:

```
WHERE Exit_Date >= DATEADD(day, -90, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
  AND Exit_Date <  DATEADD(day, -89, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want data from 90 days ago, then use:

```
WHERE Exit_Date >= DATEADD(day, -90, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) AND
      Exit_Date < DATEADD(day, -89, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

This gets results from exactly 90 days ago.

Note the conversion to `DATE`.  Despite its name, `GETDATE()` has a time component.